# Excision in cohomology with supports

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have been trying to solve exercise III.2.3f from Hartshorne.

> Let $V$ be an open subset if $X$ and $Y$ be a closed subset in $X$ such that $Y \subset V$. Then there exist a functorial isomorphism, for all $i$ and $\mathscr{F}$,
>
> $$H^i_Y (X, \mathscr{F}) \cong H^i_Y(V, \mathscr{F}|_V)$$

---

**My approach**

Let us consider the exact sequence:
$$0 \to j_!(\mathscr{F}|_V) = \mathscr{F}_V \to \mathscr{F} \to i_*(\mathscr{F}|_Z)=\mathscr{F}_Z \to 0$$
where $Z = X - V$.

Then we consider the corresponding long exact sequence:
$$\cdots \to H^i_Y (X, \mathscr{F}_V) \to H^i_Y (X, \mathscr{F}) \to H^i_Y(X, \mathscr{F}_Z) \to H^{i+1}_Y(X, \mathscr{F}_V) \to \cdots$$

As $Z \cap Y = \emptyset$, $H^i_Y(X, \mathscr{F}_Z) = 0$. [I'm not sure why. My idea involves taking injective resolution by sheaves of discontinuous sections].

Then $H^i_Y (X, \mathscr{F}_V) \cong H^i_Y (X, \mathscr{F})$ for all $i$ and also functorially.

Now, we have to show $H^i_Y (X, \mathscr{F}_V) \cong H^i_Y (V, \mathscr{F}|_V)$. [This seems intuitive but I don't know how to prove]

Any hint or idea will be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\renewcommand{\G}{\Gamma}\renewcommand{\d}{\delta}\renewcommand{\cF}{\mathcal{F}}\renewcommand{\Supp}{\operatorname{Supp}}$ Here's an easier way: since $H^i_Y(X,-)$ and $H^i_Y(V,(-)|_V)$ are both universal $\d$-functors, it suffices to show a natural isomorphism between $\G_Y(X,-)$ and $\G_Y(V,(-)|_V)$ by corollary III.1.4.
There's a natural restriction map $\G_Y(X,\cF)\to \G_Y(V,\cF|_V)$ for any $\cF$, and I claim this is an isomorphism.
It is injective: the kernel is the sections $s$ satisfying $\Supp(s)\subset X\setminus V$ and $\Supp(s)\subset Y$, but $X\setminus V$ does not meet $Y$ and thus any such section must be zero.
It is surjective: given any section $s\in\G_Y(V,\cF|_V)$, it is zero on the open set $V\setminus Y$, so it glues with the section $0$ on $X\setminus Y$ to form a section of $\cF$ over $X$ supported on $Y$ which restricts to $s$ on $V$.

Comment: Is there a quick way to see that $H_Y^i(V, (-)|_V)$ is a universal $\delta$-functor? The way I see this is that since exactness is stalk-local, $(-)|_V$ preserves exact sequences so then it is easy enough to check that $H_Y^i(V, (-)|_V)$ is a $\delta$ functor. Then since $H_Y^i(V, -)$ is effaceable, we get an $M$ that also works for $\mathcal{F}|_V$, so $H_Y^i(V, (-)|_V)$ is effaceable. Then apply Theorem 1.3A to deduce $H_Y^i(V, (-)|_V)$ is universal. However, this leaves me a bit dissatisfied since I need to blackbox 1.3A. Regardless, Is this the idea?

Comment: @JakeZweifler Sounds right, but I'm not checking your work super thoroughly. You're going to use theorem III.1.3A a few other times in Hartshorne, so you might as well get comfortable with it. Whether that means black-boxing it, reading Tohoku, or going and proving it yourself (it's not that bad!), you should do what you need. FWIW, I think Hartshorne's really brief on homological algebra and assumes you've taken a course on it independent of his work, and I think it's a good idea to spend time on it independent of AG.

Comment: fair enough! Thanks for the quick response.